# Android snippet for Check for updates

Tags: android, code-snippets, updates

I have developed an Android application.Can anyone suggest me the best Android snippet for checking for the newest version in android market when my application launches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do that, Android Market automatically checks for updates and displays notifications if new versions of software becomes available.

Comment: I have a few apps on the Market and I dont. As soon as the android device is connected to the internet, the Market automatically checks if there are new versions and offers to download them.